# I am having a problem in the game I coded in JS/DOM (problem described in the body)

Tags: javascript

I have coded this "sort of chess game" where the goal is to place 8 queens without them being able to hit each other, so far I have made the whole program and it is working wonderful! I just have one problem, you are able to place a queen on top of another queen. If you do this the game automatically stops. If anyone have any idea on how I can fix this problem, it would mean a lot!!!! (There are also some norwegian variable names in the code, if you need any translation or things like that I will gladly help with that)

Thanks in advance!!!

```js
let knappEl = document.querySelector("button")
knappEl.addEventListener("click", restart)

let tableEl = document.querySelector("table")
let liste = []
let turTeller = 0
let slatt = false
let meldingEl = document.querySelector("#melding")

for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  let trEl = document.createElement('tr');
  for (let j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    let tdEl = document.createElement('td');
    tdEl.setAttribute("id", "rute" + i + j)
    tdEl.addEventListener("click", plasserTårn)
    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
    // Bare på grunn av css
    tdEl.className = (i % 2 === j % 2) ? "hvit firkant" : "svart firkant";
  }
  tableEl.appendChild(trEl);
}

function plasserTårn(e) {
  if (slatt == false) {
    let trykketFirkant = e.target
    let plassertBrikke = {
      rad: trykketFirkant.id.substring(5, 4),
      kolonne: trykketFirkant.id.substring(6, 5)
    }
    console.log(liste)
    console.log(plassertBrikke)
    if (turTeller == 0) {
      if (firkantTrykket = e.target) {
        firkantTrykket.innerHTML = "<img src='https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/97-971641_2d-chess-queen-hd-png-download.png' width='50px' height='50px'>";
      }
      turTeller = 1
    } else if (turTeller == 1) {
      if (firkantTrykket = e.target) {
        firkantTrykket.innerHTML = "<img src='https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/219-2191738_chess-piece-silhouette-black-queen-chess.png' width='50px' height='50px'>";
      }
      turTeller = 0
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
      let r = Math.abs(liste[i].rad - plassertBrikke.rad)
      let k = Math.abs(liste[i].kolonne - plassertBrikke.kolonne)
      if (liste[i].rad == plassertBrikke.rad || liste[i].kolonne == plassertBrikke.kolonne || r == k) {
        meldingEl.innerHTML = "En dronning har blir slått"
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        slatt = true
      } else if (liste.length == 7) {
        meldingEl.innerHTML = "Du har vunnet!"
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        slatt = true
      }
    }
    liste.push(plassertBrikke)
  } else {
    meldingEl.innerHTML = "Spillet er over!"
  }
}

function restart() {
  location.reload()
  window.scrollTo(500, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.6em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 2px purple;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 2px purple;
}

.board {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 440px;
  height: 440px;
  border: 32px solid;
  border-color: darkslategray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.firkant {
  resize: none;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  border: -1px black solid;
}

.hvit {
  background: white;
}

.svart {
  background: grey;
}

td:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer
}

button {
  color: rgb(150, 12, 177);
  border: solid 1px white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Dronningspillet</h3>

<table class="board"></table>


<p id="melding"></p>

<button>Prøv igjen!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a lot of typos in there... You created a variable in the if statement (**`firkantTrykket`**`= e.target`), which you shouldn't, and you didn't check whether the target is an `img` tag or not.

**This code should work just fine:**

```js
let knappEl = document.querySelector("button")
knappEl.addEventListener("click", restart)

let tableEl = document.querySelector("table")
let liste = []
let turTeller = 0
let slatt = false
let meldingEl = document.querySelector("#melding")

for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  let trEl = document.createElement('tr');
  for (let j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    let tdEl = document.createElement('td');
    tdEl.setAttribute("id", "rute" + i + j)
    tdEl.addEventListener("click", plasserTårn)
    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
    // Bare på grunn av css
    tdEl.className = (i % 2 === j % 2) ? "hvit firkant" : "svart firkant";
  }
  tableEl.appendChild(trEl);
}

function plasserTårn(e) {
  if (slatt == false) {
    let trykketFirkant = e.target
    let plassertBrikke = { rad: trykketFirkant.id.substring(5, 4), kolonne: trykketFirkant.id.substring(6, 5) }
    console.log(liste)
    console.log(trykketFirkant.tagName)
    if (trykketFirkant.tagName == 'IMG') return; // stops the function if the target is the img tag
    if (turTeller == 0) {
      trykketFirkant.innerHTML = "<img src='https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/97-971641_2d-chess-queen-hd-png-download.png' width='50px' height='50px'>";
      turTeller = 1
    }
    else if (turTeller == 1) {
      trykketFirkant.innerHTML = "<img src='https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/219-2191738_chess-piece-silhouette-black-queen-chess.png' width='50px' height='50px'>";
      turTeller = 0
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
      let r = Math.abs(liste[i].rad - plassertBrikke.rad)
      let k = Math.abs(liste[i].kolonne - plassertBrikke.kolonne)
      if (liste[i].rad == plassertBrikke.rad || liste[i].kolonne == plassertBrikke.kolonne || r == k) {
        meldingEl.innerHTML = "En dronning har blir slått"
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        slatt = true
      }
      else if (liste.length == 7) {
        meldingEl.innerHTML = "Du har vunnet!"
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        slatt = true
      }
    }
    liste.push(plassertBrikke)
  }
  else {
    meldingEl.innerHTML = "Spillet er over!"
  }
}

function restart() {
  location.reload()
  window.scrollTo(500, 0);
}
```